# What's the meaning GetNativeTexturePtr() of Texture2D?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I create a Texture2D object in C# script, and want to render somethings by OpenGL ES from a C++ plugin. In some samples' native codes, I noticed that texture ptr could be converted to texture ID like this:

```
NATIVE_API void init(void* texHandle)
{
    g_texId = (GLuint)(size_t)(texHandle);
}
```

When I try to do that as well, I got a very big integer number, seemingly not a correct texture ID, so what's the texture Ptr exact meaning? Why Unity don't return an integer for texture ID?

Comment: what is `GetNativeTextureID` where did you see that one? In the API only [`GetNativeTexturePtr`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture.GetNativeTexturePtr.html) exists .. which would be the main difference I can tell from what I know ^^

Comment: GetNativeTextureID is old API, it was discarded.

Comment: I solve this problem by reset some Project settings, Unity Editor-> Edit Menu -> Project Settings -> Player -> Other Settings -> Graphics APIs -> select OpenGLES3